# When activity theme is set programmatically it has black background

Tags: android

I need to change theme of the activity programmatically. Theme can be "classic" - regular Android app window or transparent window (similar to Theme.Dialog).

If I set the theme in manifest, it works as expected.

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Dialog" ...
```

[image]

If I set it programatically (the very same theme), background is black.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setTheme(R.style.Dialog);

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
 }
 // Now in manifest the theme isn't set
```

[image]

The issue is that background is black. Is there a solution how to do set Dialog theme programmatically ?
(I tried to set background of layout, etc. explicitly in XML and code but it didn't help.)

Whole code

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jc.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            >
            <!--android:theme="@style/Dialog"-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
    <style name="Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00ff0000">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff00"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.jc.myapplication;

import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setTheme(R.style.Dialog);

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)).setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
  //getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
 }
}
```